# Magento Hosting recommendations to speed up dynamic pages

Tags: hosting, optimization

We have a pretty huge and complex setup in Magento, but are experiencing some speed issues.

The static pages generally are not fast enough, although Varnish has been setup, which has helped quite a bit.
The dynamic pages are too slow - it takes up to 30 seconds to open up the payment window.

Our developers have optimized the site completely, and our host has upgraded the server and database several times, but it seems as if the communication between them, is not going as smoothly as it should, and we are now stuck.

What are your experiences with hosting? Do you have any recommendations?

We currently have 1000 visitors a day, and it's growing rather fast.

We currently have: 
Firewall, 1 CPU, 512mb RAM 
Loadbalancer, 1 CPU, 2GB RAM 
Webserver, 2 CPU, 4GB RAM, Apache 2.4 and PHP-FPM 5.6 
Data-server, 1 CPU, 2GB RAM 
Db1-server, 6 CPU, 12GB RAM 
Memcache server, 1 CPU, 512mb RAM

Comment: I'm afraid you would have to add more information on your setup, the specifics on the installation and data so we have a remote chance to help you. The scope of the question may still be too broad or based more on opinions than facts which also is out of the scope for this site. However: welcome to Magento SE and I do hope we'll be able to help you!

Comment: How many visitors per day, or browsing website at single moment do you have? Just to be sure that problem is really in hosting, but not Magento extensions.

Comment: Hey!
We currently have 1000 visitors a day, and it's growing rather fast.
We currently have: 
Firewall: (1 CPU, 512mb RAM)
Loadbalancer: (1 CPU, 2GB RAM)
Webserver: (2 CPU, 4GB RAM, Apache 2.4 and PHP-FPM 5.6)
Data-server: (1 CPU, 2GB RAM)
Db1-server: (6 CPU, 12GB RAM)
Memcache server, 1 CPU, 512mb RAM

Thanks

Comment: Ok here's a quick breakdown for things to look at:

1) Setup full page cache (google this for Magento)
2) Evaluate pages that have too many items loaded and setup a lazyload extension
3) Need to optimize Magento database (hopefully your host has expertise here)
4) Get web server with fast CPU (GHz). This will directly impact the speed at which the PHP files can be processed and loaded. SSD on the DB server will help too.

That's a *very* basic outline. Above and beyond that it can be very complex. Find me on linkedin and I'd be glad to look at it with you and lend a hand.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you self-host this on someone's development PC in the office? Does it take 30 seconds to page load?

With this 'simple test' of creating a local replica you will be able to determine whether the problem is with your Magento build or with the hosting company or even the network. From there you will be able to decide whether to get new hosting (or new developers).

Although your developers have optimised everything, it must still be possible to see where the bottleneck is. This you must identify if you are to fix things. In most Magento builds the bottleneck is with PHP rather than in the database or web server. What is the 'time to first byte' for your site? If that is a long time then there is your PHP problem.

Comment: If we host it on a local PC we see a slight improvement in speed, but still not enough at all

Comment: What is an acceptable time to first byte?

Answer (score 0):

You need a magento stack.
It's not all about caching. You can use redis, varnish and zend opcache. 
But you need solr and fact filter for filtering. 
The best magento stack is above;
[image]